# How to point abc.customerdomain.com to http://example.com/abc with browser showing the former domain?

Tags: .htaccess

The domain name of my business partner in China is customerdomain.com. This domain is for their server in China.

We wish to point abc.customerdomain.com to http://example.com/abc on my server in USA. The viewers should see abc.customerdomain.com as the URL on their browsers when arriving at http://example.com/abc

How do I set up this in cPanel of example.com? My customer has pointed abc.customerdomain.com to my IP address.

I am using cPanel. I have tried ADDON DOMAIN and ALIASES but it gave errors.

(XID ts9ujm) Sorry, the domain is already pointed to an IP address that does not appear to use DNS servers associated with this server. Please transfer the domain to this servers nameservers or have your administrator add one of its nameservers to /etc/ips.remotedns and make the proper A entries on that remote nameserver.

Comment: It is unclear what the past paragraph in your question is meant to express, I will ignore it in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your http server needs to respond to reqeusts to `abc.customerdomain.com`. Then you have two options: either you can do a direct internal rewrite to specific resources, *if your server side logic allows that* , or you can use the http servers proxy module to internally forward the request to the host `example.com`, *if that module is loaded and activated inside the http server* .

The first option is faster:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.customerdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /abc/$1 [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

The second option might be safer if you have a server side logic which does not work with the first option:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.customerdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.com/abc/$1 [P,QSA]
```

These rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).